# Invoke macro with variable name in Cmake

Tags: cmake

I'd like to be able to do this (if possible (trying to get pseudo polymorphism/function passing to avoid copy-paste))

```
 macro(do_A x)
 endmacro()

 macro(do_B x)
 endmacro()

 macro(C y x)
 do_${x}(y)
 endmacro()

 C(asdf,A)
```

Is there any mechanism to do such a thing?

Edit: it may be more accurate to ask, can you pass a macro as an argument to another macro?

Comment: Removed language tags to prevent you from downvotes ;) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a better way, but you can use [`configure_file`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/configure_file.html) and [`include`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include.html) here as helpers.

So, if you create an input file called "macro_helper.cmake.in" and have its contents as just the following line:

```
@MacroName@(MacroArg)
```

Then you can configure this to a per-macro output file, and simply then `include` the output file:

```
macro(C MacroArg MacroId)
  set(MacroName do_${MacroId})
  # Need to make MacroArg a "proper" variable since we're in a macro, not a
  # function.  Run 'cmake --help-command macro' for more info.
  set(MacroArg ${MacroArg})
  set(OutputFile ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/helpers/macro_helper_${MacroId}.cmake)
  configure_file(macro_helper.cmake.in ${OutputFile} @ONLY)
  include(${OutputFile})
endmacro()
```

Note: you don't want the comma when invoking `C` - just do:

```
C(asdf A)
```